# Making floated elements collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to make sure floated elements collapse to fill all available space instead of breaking onto a new line?

In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/mjfoxr4p/ you'll see `block 9` and `block 23` are leaving an unwanted empty space

A JS solution would be fine if this can't be don't using css only.

Comment: you may use a jQuery plugin for that http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

I tend to reach for [Shuffle](http://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/adding-removing/) when I am making dynamically resizing grids. I am not aware of a pure CSS way to accomplish this.